# Как определить что ViewPAger достиг края?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewpager

Мне необходимо однозначно определить, что ViewPager домотан до конца. Т.е. пользователь "тянет" `ViewPager` за "край" (надеюсь понятно). В этот момент, я должен заменить текущий фрагмент на новый (с помощью анимации это будет выглядит как перелистывание ViewPager-а). Но вот вопрос: как понять, что ViewPager достиг правого и левого края?

Я пробовал решить задачу с помощью просто математики, вот так:

```
private fun getViewPagerListener(): OnPageChangeListener {
    return object : OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            if (position + positionOffset  == 0f) { // first page
                println("LEFT")
            } else if (position + positionOffset == 5f) { // 5th, the last page
                println("RIGHT")
            }
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
        }
    }
}
```

Но при такой реализации получается большое кол-во ложных срабатываний + из крайних позиций, `OnPageChangeListener` не всегда отзывается (находясь на 1 вкладке и мотая влево, листенер в 70% не сработает, все зависит от того как положить палец. Аналогичная проблема справа). Если у кого есть идеи, пожалуйста напишите их мне) Спасибо!

Comment: Я думаю, что с точки зрения UX вы изобретаете что-то совершенно дизориентирующее пользователя.

Comment: UX для каждого проекта свой, решения тоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я приведу небольшой прототип, который у меня получился. Идя такая:

Необходимо реагировать только в том случае, когда устанавливается состояние `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` (т.е. пользователь только что перестал скроллить ViewPager). Для того, чтобы определить положение "за край" необходимо: во-первых - знать, что мы находимся на одной из крайних вкладок, а во-вторых - знать что пользователь тянет в нужную сторону (за край ViewPager). Если скролим в "край", то состояние ViewPager не измениться, а значит, если предыдущее и текущие состояния равны - пользователь пытается перейти "за край". Реализовал я это так:

```
private fun getViewPagerListener(): OnPageChangeListener {
    return object : OnPageChangeListener {
        var previousPosition = -1
        var currentPosition = 0

        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {  }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            currentPosition = position
        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            if(ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE == state){
                if (currentPosition == previousPosition) {
                    if (currentPosition == 0) {
                        println("LEFT")
                    } else if (currentPosition == 5) {
                        println("RIGHT")
                    }
                }
            }

            previousPosition = currentPosition
        }
    }
}
```

Если кто-нибудь знает как решить эту проблему иначе обязательно пишите, сравнимся. К тому же я с большей охотой отдам ответ тому кто предложит красивое решение.